# How to delete records from CTE (Common Table Expression) in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I have written a following query using CTE in Postgres. Now I am unable to delete records from it.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
   
        firstname, 
        lastname, 
        country, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                firstname, 
                lastname, 
                country
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        employee
) 
delete  from cte
where row_num >1
```

When I run this query it show me error:

> relation "cte" does not exist

Here is sample of my table 'employee'

```
id  firstname  lastname  country
1   "Raj"      "Gupta"   "India"
2   "Raj"      "Gupta"   "India"
3   "Mohan"    "Kumar"   "USA"
4   "James"    "Barry"   "UK"
5   "James"    "Barry"   "UK"
6   "James"    "Barry"   "UK"
```

Comment: Please provide a sample data of employee table. :-)

Comment: @Linker I Have edit my question and added a sample of table employee in it. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Deleting from a CTE is not possible.

You can do like this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cd75cbc0415861c1ee97be7c3ef8882a)

```
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY firstname, lastname, country) row_num
        FROM 
            employee
    ) s
    WHERE row_num > 1
)
```

If you want to use a CTE nevertheless, you can move the subquery into one:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b0b22593329e003e0620051a4b47c1c)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY firstname, lastname, country) row_num
        FROM 
            employee
    ) s
    WHERE row_num > 1
)
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete record from CTE table in postgresql. Although it is possible in other DB server like SQLSERVER.
You can see [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) document for postgresql.

Comment: I find this [sample for sqlserver](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server-from-a-table2/#:~:text=Delete%20duplicate%20rows%2Frecords%20in%20SQL%20server%20using%20common,Use%20DELETE%20statement%20to%20remove%20the%20duplicate%20rows.) that looks just like what OP is doing

Comment: What does the sql standards say about cte? Could you provide some external links?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using:

```
delete from employee e
    where e.id > (select min(e2.id)
                  from employee e2
                  where e2.firstname = e.firstname and
                        e2.lastname = e.lastname and 
                        e2.country = e.country
                 );
```

This is standard SQL and will work in both SQL Server and Postgres.

The only difference from the SQL Server version is how `NULL` values are treated.  This treats them as all being "different" so a matching `NULL` values would not be considered a match.  This is probably not an issue in your data, but you can use:

```
                  where e2.firstname is not distinct from e.firstname and
                        e2.lastname is not distinct from e.lastname and 
                        e2.country is not distinct from e.country
```

If you want `NULL` values to match.

Note that the original version should be able to make use of an index on `(lastname, firstname, country, id)` (in either database).

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me as you cannot delete on cte on postgres:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) * FROM your_table;
DELETE FROM your_table;
INSERT INTO your_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think better case will be just to filter not needed rows on step of creating CTE (without any deleting)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        firstname, 
        lastname, 
        country, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                firstname, 
                lastname, 
                country
        ) row_num
     FROM employee
     WHERE row_num >1
)
```